# how to set two class name for Ember.js input helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember.js-view

i'm trying to bind an input element like this:

```
{{input value=email type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class=emailError:with-error}}
```

it works just fine, as long as I try to assign it only 1 class name ".with-error".
how can I assign 2 class names, so it will be: ".with-error .second-class"?
I know how to do it with:

```
{{bind-attr class=":secondClass emailError:with-error"}}
```

but this doesn't work with input helper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This feature is not well documented, but when defining attributes on a Handlebars helper, you can either leave out the quotes to indicate that you want the value of the attribute to be a bound variable, or you can add the suffix "Binding" and then use quotes with an expression similar to the one you would use with `{{bind-attr}}`.

So, in your case, the following should work:

```
{{input value=email type="text" placeholder="Enter email" classBinding="emailError:with-error :myClassName"}}
```

Note how instead of `class=myBoundValues` we are using `classBinding="myBoundValue"`.